# How to handle empty variables in a try/catch block?

Tags: c#, try-catch

So I have button that sends a `POST` request along with two variables, an outbox ID called `oid`, and an `email`. The controller takes in the variables and performs a method call, the end goal would be to send a `JSON` response back depending on whether it fails or succeeds.

I have the following written for the controller:

```cs
public ActionResult ResendEmail(int oid, string email = null)
{
    try
    {
        Outbox.ResendEmail(oid, email);
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Email has been queued to be resent", status = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occurred when attempting to resend the email", status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError });
    }
}
```

Problem here, is that 1. If the `oid` and/or `email` is empty, the method call for `Outbox.ResendEmail(oid, email)` will still be called and a success json response will be returned. I'm also unsure if this is a proper way to use try/catch.

Feels like I should re-write how i'm handling this. Maybe an if statement to check for an existing `oid` and `email` followed by a try/catch?

Comment: Sure you can do a sanity check with `if`, and it would imo actually be a good idea. But why do you think you would then still need a try-catch for simply sending back the success=false response? I feel there is more to your question than you told us -- or i completely misunderstand what you are trying to ask...

Comment: Wouldn't I need the try/catch to handle null variables being passed down to it? I assumed I could write something like `if (email == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email))` and then use the catch to return the `JSON` response. Is this incorrect?

Comment: What's the point of throwing a pointless exception if you could just send the json response right there? If you want to keep the existing try-catch, perhaps move the line sending the error response below the try-catch clause and safe-guard the calling of  Outbox.ResendEmail and sending the success=true response by the sanity checks. Hence, if the sanity check will fail, Outbox.ResendEmail and sending the success=true response will not happen, and the code "falls through" the try-catch and reaching the line sending the error response after the try-catch block...

Comment: Got it! Your response and the answer below cleared it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The try/catch is useful for handling *exceptions*. If `Outbox.ResendEmail()` throws an exception, then the try/catch will do its thing.

However, if `Outbox.ResendEmail()` will not throw an exception when given an incorrect `oid` or an incorrect, empty, or null `email`, then you need something else, such as an if-statement.

In addition, it probably is not appropriate to return a 500 error due to invalid parameters. It's not really a server error if the user passes a null email address.

I would recommend something like the following:

```
public ActionResult ResendEmail(int oid, string email = null)
{
    // If you have a way to validate the oid, then use that instead of just checking for 0:
    if (oid == 0)
    {
        return // one of the 400 level responses
    }

    // Do you have a way to validate the email address?
    // If so, probably do that here, depending on how Outbox.ResendEmail() behaves
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
    {
        return // one of the 400 level responses
    }

    try
    {
        Outbox.ResendEmail(oid, email);
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Email has been queued to be resent", status = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occurred when attempting to resend the email", status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError });
    }
}
```

Comment: This clears it up. The `email` is actually not coming in from a form, it's being passed down from a row in a grid (same wit the `oid`) so there's no validation for it. Just want to make sure that if the specific row doesn't have an email there then it sends an appropiate mesasge like "Email address and email is blank or does not exist" along with a 400. Gets a bit confusing since i'm not exactly submitting a form, just resending an existing email.

Answer (score 0):

Try Catch always work with exception. As per the below statement in your question, it seems that **Outbox.ResendEmail** does not throw exception

> If the oid and/or email is empty, the method call for
> Outbox.ResendEmail(oid, email) will still be called and a success json
> response will be returned. I'm also unsure if this is a proper way to
> use try/catch

instead of exception, it may be returning response with status false or error or not 200. That why, it is not going to catch and returning json response with success = false.

**you can do like this**

```
public ActionResult ResendEmail(int oid, string email = null)
{
   if ( oid <=0 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) || validation of email if any)
    { 
      return response; // with statuscode among 400 and proper message in response 
                      //that where is the problem in request.
    } 

    try
    {
        var response= Outbox.ResendEmail(oid, email);
        if (response.StatusCode == 200) // condition for check that response is false or success 
        {
          return Json(new { success = true, message = "Email has been queued to be resent", status = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK });
        }

        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occurred when attempting to resend the email", status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError });


    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occurred when attempting to resend the email", status = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError });
    }
}
```